# VF ? vf ? VisualForce? other?

Tags: discussion

Title asks the question:

I don't think everyone will follow on what we decide, but this is mainly for when editing a question: Shall we capitalize it?  leave as is?

The options are:

VF

vf - defo a not!

VisualForce

Visual Force

Answer (score 9):

It's actually [Visualforce](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index.htm) - no capital 'F'. I'll correct it if I'm in there correcting something else...

Answer (score 4):

I always use VF
Having to type VisualForce several times within an answer is likely to drive you up the wall!

Comment: Agreed, I think use of either VisualForce of VF are both acceptable, though we shouldn't got out of our way to edit where somebody doesn't conform either.

Comment: In question titles I think it's good to expand it to Visualforce, just because it looks better and probably gets better Google juice - folks are more likely to google Visualforce than VF.

Comment: Thats a very valid point, Im also thinking that it may also depend on the target audience? Apex dev's will probably shorten it to 'VF' but point and click users will probably use the full 'Visualforce'

Comment: I agree with @LaceySnr in that I wouldn't go out of my way to edit that. As for the Google results, couldn't we just setup synonym tags for VF and Visualforce? Would that take care of the issue?